# ¿Por qué se puede modificar el SeriaVersionUID?

Tags: java

¿Qué sentido tiene modificar el serialVersionUID?

Por lo que vi en un curso, mientras el serialVersionUID sea el mismo (serialVersionUID = 1L) el programa que recibe esa instancia podrá leerla. Ahora si quien recibe el .dat cambia una propiedad de nombre, ¿por qué sigue pudiendo leer la instancia sin problemas?

Por lo que entiendo el serialVersionUID se crea para controlar que la instancia enviada tenga lo necesario para poder ser leida en el programa receptor; ahora si en este caso le cambio una propiedad, el serialVersion cambiará y no se podrá leer.

Ahora la duda, ¿por qué en el primer caso me deja leer el archivo sin ningún problema?

El código:

```
public class Serializando {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Administrador jefe = new Administrador("Juan",2000,1998,11,24);

        Empleado []personal = new Empleado[3];

        personal[0] = jefe;
        personal[1] = new Empleado("Ana",400,1999,5,29);
        personal[2] = new Empleado("Lautaro",500,2012,6,5);

        try {

/*            ObjectOutputStream escribiendo = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/MatiEzelQ/Documents/Java SE/Curso/src/AccesoAFicheros/Objeto.dat"));
            escribiendo.writeObject(personal);
            escribiendo.close();*/

            ObjectInputStream leyendo = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("/Users/MatiEzelQ/Documents/Java SE/Curso/src/AccesoAFicheros/Objeto.dat"));

            try {

                Empleado []empleadosRecuperados = (Empleado[])leyendo.readObject();

                for (int i=0; i<empleadosRecuperados.length;i++) {
                    System.out.println(empleadosRecuperados[i]);
                }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}

            leyendo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }

}


class Empleado implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private String nombre;
    private double sueldo;
    Date fechaContrato;

    public Empleado(String n, double s, int agno, int mes, int dia) {

        nombre = n;
        sueldo = s;

        GregorianCalendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar(agno,mes-1,dia);
        fechaContrato = calendario.getTime();
    }


    public void subirSueldo(int porcentaje) {

        sueldo += sueldo * porcentaje / 100;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Nombre: " + nombre + ". Sueldo: " + sueldo + ". Fecha de contrato: " + fechaContrato;
    }


    //Getters-Setters

    public Date getFechaContrato() {
        return fechaContrato;
    }
    public void setFechaContrato(Date fechaContrato) {
        this.fechaContrato = fechaContrato;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public double getSueldo() {
        return sueldo;
    }
    public void setSueldo(double sueldo) {
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }
}

class Administrador extends Empleado {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    public Administrador(String n, double s, int agno, int mes, int dia) {
        super(n, s, agno, mes, dia);

        incentivo = 0;
    }

    public double getSueldo() {
        return super.getSueldo() + incentivo;
    }

    private int incentivo;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar qué cambios se han realizado en la clase antes de intentar deserializarla? O mejor aún, ¿podrías colocar ejemplo en código que muestre tu duda en más detalle?

Comment: Supone que el archivo .dat ya lo tengo guardado. (La variable sueldo en vez de llamarse "sueldo" se llama "sueldos" y después la cambie para leer el archivo y comprobar si funcionaba y lo hizo)

Comment: Pues si cambio de nombre a un campo no hay ningún efecto negativo ni abominable puesto que la clase mantiene la misma estructura, esto es, mismo número de campos y mismos tipos de datos para los campos declarados. Por ello es que tu prueba funciona. El caso que discuten en el curso es que si cambias el valor del `serialVersionUID` en la clase a pesar que no cambia la estructura de la clase, la deserialización fallará.

Comment: Claro, pero para que serviría ponerle un serialVersionUID propio? No sería mas seguro que el compilador lo haga? Asi se evitaria errores

Comment: Yo lo hago más fácil: no lo declaro.

Comment: Es un tema raro este de la serializacion u.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El campo `static final long serialVersionUID` se declara para las clases que implementan la interfaz [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). La documentación de la clase explica qué es este campo y para qué se utiliza. Acá coloco los textos principales de la documentación para utilizar en la respuesta:

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization (...) A serializable class can declare its own serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named "serialVersionUID" that must be `static`, `final`, and of type `long`
>
> (...)
>
> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the class (...)  However, it is *strongly recommended* that all serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected `InvalidClassExceptions` during deserialization

Traducido:

> La ejecución de la serialización asocia cada clase serializable con un número de versión, llamado serialVersionUID, el cual se usa durante la deserialización para verificar que el remitente y el receptor de un objeto serializado han cargado las clases para ese objeto que son compatibles respecto a la serialización (...) Una clase serializable puede declarar su propio serialVersionUID explícitamente al declarar un campo llamado `serialVersionUID` que debe ser `static` (estático), `final` (final) y de tipo `long`
>
> (...)
>
> Si una clase serializable no declara explícitamente un serialVersionUID, entonces la ejecución de la serialización calculará un valor por defecto de serialVersionUID para la clase basada en varios aspectos de la clase (...) Sin embargo, se *recomienda fuertemente* que todas las clases serializables explícitamente declaren valores para serialVersionUID, porque el cálculo por defecto de serialVersionUID es altamente sensible a los detalles de la clase que pueden variar dependiendo de la implementación del compilador y puede así resultar en excepciones de tipo `InvalidClassException` inesperadas durante la deserialización.

Tal como lo indica la documentación, el hecho de tener la capacidad de declarar el campo `serialVersionUID` es para mantener un valor estándar al momento de serializar y deserializar los objetos de una clase. Este es el caso principalmente cuando tienes tus objetos serializados en un archivo (en este caso mencionas tu .dat) y lo has serializado utilizando una clase compilada en Windows Vista de 32 bits con JDK 1.6 u32 y este archivo lo lees desde una computadora  Ubuntu 14 de 64 bits con JDK 1.8 u45 donde la misma clase ha sido recompilada. Entonces, al existir la diferencia de sistema operativo, Java puede utilizar el valor que has declarado en la clase para serialVersionUID y facilitar la comprobación de que el objeto a deserializar es compatible con la clase cargada en la ejecución del programa.

¿Para qué lo puedes modificar? Porque así tu aplicación puede fallar de inmediato al intentar deserializar un objeto cuya versión no es la última de la clase a la que corresponde. Esto se conoce como [fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) (no encontré un artículo correspondiente en español)

Se recomienda bastante que declares este campo y que lo modifiques solo si has modificado la estructura de campos de la clase. Asimismo, si no se te ocurre qué valor asignarle, puedes dejarle esa labor al IDE, he visto que Eclipse e IntelliJ Idea lo hacen muy bien.

Comment: Es indistinto, porque si lo generas tú o el IDE, el campo estará allí declarado. Lo único que cambiará será el valor. Luego de eso, depende de los mantenedores de la clase de actualizar ese valor apropiadamente al cambiar la estructura de campos de la clase.